# Unix to linux migration - unix2dos

Tags: linux, unix, migration

I am migrating my code from UNIX to LINUX and I know unix2dos command is not available in SUSE 11.0. Please let me know if

```
alias unix2dos='recode lat1..ibmpc'
```

will have the same effect as that of unix2dos?

Comment: Why not map the line endings on the Unix box where you have `unix2dos` and only transfer the mapped files to Linux?

Comment: Because I may not have UNIX all the time available while my code is running on Linux.

Comment: why is migrating from unix to linux a reason to convert line endings? they use the same convention.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about recode, but `sed -i 's/$/\r/'` would do the same thing as `unix2dos`.

Comment: Actually I do have huge files and sed/perl could bring down the performance.

Comment: I can't imagine any *nix tool getting this done faster than `sed`.  Give it a shot on a big file and see what the speed is.

Comment: @SachinChourasiya It [appears](http://www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/RZ/software/gnu/utilities/recode_3.html#SEC8) that `recode` is for switching between character encoding.  This is almost *guaranteed* to be slower than the `sed` version, which simply adds on character on each line instead of remapping the entire file to a new encoding.

Comment: Alright, I agree this could be done via sed, however how about using it like I mentioned above? Any pitfalls anyone can see?

Comment: @SachinChourasiya Other than the fact that `recode` doesn't seem to be meant for this sort of job, and would probably be slower than `sed`, I don't see any problem in particular.  I did see [your exact `recode` command](http://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2000/10/msg00217.html) on a SUSE mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

Using `recode` seems risky, it's used for converting character sets, not just changing newline characters. I haven't used `recode` but I'm afraid that you could break your files if they are encoded in e.g. UTF-8 instead of Latin1.

I don't know what packages are found in SUSE, but perhaps there is one of the alternatives to `unix2dos`, like `todos` (on Debian found in package `tofromdos`).

Using `sed` as other suggested should work well. If you are really worried about performance, you could compare `sed`'s performance to `awk '{print $0 "\r"}'` - I can't say for sure which will be faster in your case but it won't hurt to measure both on a sample of your files.

Answer (score 0):

Load your file(s) into vim, then

`:set ff=dos`  -- Changes to DOS line endings (CRLF)

`:set ff=unix` -- Changes to unix line endings (LF)

Comment: Loading a large file in vim could take a *loooong* time to render.  Plus, you can't execute that from the command line directly.

Comment: @TimPote: Works fine from the vim command line here.  I did not test it directly from the invocation command line (bash, cmd.exe etc).  Takes a few seconds to load a 20ish megabyte file in vim and convert it.  Good enough for me.